# How to extract functions used in a python code file?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to create a list of all the functions used in a code file. For example if we have following code in a file named 'add_random.py'

`

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg

def foo():
    print np.random.rand(4) + np.random.randn(4)
    print linalg.norm(np.random.rand(4))
```

`

I would like to extract the following list:

    `[numpy.random.rand, np.random.randn, np.linalg.norm, np.random.rand]`

The list contains the functions used in the code with their actual name in the form of 'module.submodule.function'. Is there something built in python language that can help me do this?

Comment: This is not as easy as you think it might be. What about callables stored as references in something else? Say you have a dictionary with `{'foo': np.random.rand, 'bar': linalg.norm}` then use those callables via the keys in the dictionary. Take into account that your code can then rebind those keys too, dynamically swapping out names..

Comment: In other words, resolving the full qualified names is not necessarily straightforward nor cut and dry.

Comment: That said, you can capture all `ast.Call` nodes and extract the `func` expression (it'll be a smaller tree of `ast` nodes, including `ast.Name` and `ast.Attribute`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you think it might be good idea to parse the code as a string and extract out particular patterns and then do multiple passes until one gets the full paths to all functions used?

Comment: I don't think multiple passes are going to work; there are basic limitations to static code analysis here, dynamic code is just too dynamic.

Comment: You could do this with static analysis, in fact your example didn’t say which functions that actually were used by code path, but ones that are written as in your example.   The only real problem is our horrific tooling.... and academic post-modernists, who value cynicism over silence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extract all call expressions with:

```
import ast

class CallCollector(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.calls = []
        self.current = None

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        # new call, trace the function expression
        self.current = ''
        self.visit(node.func)
        self.calls.append(self.current)
        self.current = None

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        if self.current is not None:
            print "warning: {} node in function expression not supported".format(
                node.__class__.__name__)
        super(CallCollector, self).generic_visit(node)

    # record the func expression 
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if self.current is None:
            return
        self.current += node.id

    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        if self.current is None:
            self.generic_visit(node)
        self.visit(node.value)  
        self.current += '.' + node.attr
```

Use this with a `ast` parse tree:

```
tree = ast.parse(yoursource)
cc = CallCollector()
cc.visit(tree)
print cc.calls
```

Demo:

```
>>> tree = ast.parse('''\
... def foo():
...     print np.random.rand(4) + np.random.randn(4)
...     print linalg.norm(np.random.rand(4))
... ''')
>>> cc = CallCollector()
>>> cc.visit(tree)
>>> cc.calls
['np.random.rand', 'np.random.randn', 'linalg.norm']
```

The above walker only handles names and attributes; if you need more complex expression support, you'll have to extend this.

Note that collecting names like this is **not a trivial task**. Any indirection would not be handled. You could build a dictionary in your code of functions to call and dynamically swap out function objects, and static analysis like the above won't be able to track it.

Comment: This works very well for simple function. But, fails when we have composition of functions as in `np.random.rand(4).mean()`. What should one try to do in such case? Ideally I would like to extract both `np.random.rand` as well as `mean`.

Comment: @ShishirPandey: You'll have to 'know' what the return types are of the function calls, and with a package like NumPy that requires that you have gathered that information beforehand; Python C extensions are not introspectable just yet (although Python 3.4 / 3.5 are working hard to remedy that). Rather than re-invent this wheel, perhaps you need to look at packages like [CodeIntel](https://github.com/mook/komodo-codeintel2), which lets you produce a code auto-completer for Python and other languages (SublimeCodeIntel uses it, among others).

Answer (score 3):

In general, this problem is undecidable, consider for example `getattribute(random, "random")()`.

If you want static analysis, the best there is now is [jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi)

If you accept dynamic solutions, then cover coverage is your best friend. It will show all used functions, rather than only directly referenced though.

Finally you can always roll your own dynamic instrumentation along the lines of:

```
import random
import logging

class Proxy(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        logging.debug("tried to use random.%s", name)
        return getattribute(_random, name)

_random = random
random = Proxy()
```